# How to call a command that's present within the Python script as a specific user

Tags: python, linux, python-2.6

I have this problem where a third party script that I have can be called only by a particular LINUX user due to licensing limitations. I'm using Python script to call this third party script & to pass my parameters. As my script runs as a "NOBODY" user I'm unable to execute this third party script. So I would like to change the user from nobody to this licensed user within my python script when I'm calling the command & switch back once it executes to nobody.

Below is how I'm calling the third party script within my python script,

```
__command__ = '/skint/scripts/check "%(dirname)s" "%(filename)s"'

args = {
       'dirname': dirname,
       'filename': filename
       }

command = self.__command__ % args
```

Can someone please help me on how to change the user? I'm using Python 2.6 on a Linux machine

Answer (score 0):

You have to `su` (switch user): [man page about su](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?su)

The problem here is that when the script tries to switch it will show a prompt.
To avoid this you'll have to set the sticky bit of the file and set the substitute user:

[Oracle explains here setuid() and setgid()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-4883/secfile-69/index.html)

Now, this is not really straightforward, but I can't help you more than this, I've never used it, I've only studied it in [The LPI](http://man7.org/tlpi/).

Note that on Linux it works differently than on BSD, so pay attention on what you exactly use.